# node js express cannot create route in inheritance class

Tags: node.js, inheritance, express, routes, prototype

I have Controller.js

```
var Controller = function () {

}
Controller.prototype.getAll = function (req , res) {
    console.log(this.model);
}

module.exports = Controller;
```

And StickerController.js

```
var Controller = require('./Abstract/Controller');
var util = require('util');

var StickerController  = function () {
    this.model = "StickerModel";
    Controller.apply(this);
};
util.inherits(StickerController, Controller);
module.exports = new StickerController();
```

and in router

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var StickerController = require('../controllers/StickerController');

router.get('/api/v1/stickers',Sticker.getAll);
```

it was logged undefined,
but if I'm calling out of route , it would be defined.
I have observed that 'this' in function called from route are different

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of you have called the property `getAll`, but you are using `router.get('/api/v1/stickers', Sticker.all);` try changing it to `Sticker.getAll` and it should work fine.

Comment: Actually it was  mistake , I have wrote like that